# implementation of sequenceA using traverse

Tags: haskell, types

sequenceA is implemented as following in Data.Traversable

```
 sequenceA :: Applicative f => t (f a) -> f (t a)
 sequenceA = traverse id
```

I have trouble understanding the type of `traverse id`. `traverse` has the type: `traverse :: Applicative f => (a -> f b) -> t a -> f (t b)` Its first parameter is of type: `(a -> f b)` But in the case of `sequenceA`, the type of the id function is `(a -> a)`. Where is f?

Comment: Maybe playing around in GHCi with more concrete types would help? For example, `traverse (id :: Maybe Int -> Maybe Int)` has the type `(Traversable t) => t (Maybe Int) -> Maybe (t Int)`. The `a` type parameter of `id` is separate from the `a` of `traverse`—they’re two local (type) variables that happen to have the same name. And the `a` of `id` can stand for any type of kind `*`, even a type of the form `x y` (like `Maybe Int`) or `x y z` (like `Either String Int`, or even `Int -> String` = `(->) Int String`).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's first of all say that `id` has the type `id :: c -> c` to make things *less complicated*. The `a` in a type signature of a function is *local* in the sense that the `a` of `id :: a -> a` has *nothing* to do with the `a` in `traverse :: Applicative f => (a -> f b) -> t a -> f (t b)`. `a` is just a type parameter.

So now we have the expression:

```
traverse id
```

with:

```
traverse :: Applicative f => (a -> f b) -> t a -> f (t b)
id       ::                   c -> c
```

I wrote the `c -> c` part at the same columns of the `a -> f b` part to show how the Haskell type system interacts. It now derives that:

```
a   ~ c
f b ~ c
```

So that means that `a ~ c ~ f b` and since type equality, like every equality relationship is *transitive*, it thus also means that `a ~ f b`. So now Haskell specializes `traverse id` into:

```
traverse id :: Applicative f => t a -> f (t b)
traverse id :: Applicative f => t (f b) -> f (t b) -- a ~ f b
```

So hence the type. The `id` type *in* `traverse id` has type `id :: f b -> f b`.

Comment: How could the same c have both type a and f b

Comment: But `a`, `f` and `b` are generic type *variables* as well.

Comment: @user12457 I can understand your confusion. This is about Haskell's [type inference](https://wiki.haskell.org/Type_inference). In the type signature of the traverse function `(a -> f b)` means that the function that's provided as the first argument to `traverse` should take a type `a` which can be *any* type and return an applicative type. However as you have declared `sequenceA :: Applicative f => t (f a) -> f (t a)` Haskell compiler resolves the type parameter (`a`) of the `id` function `(a -> a)` as an applicative type. So in this case `id`'s type signature can be thought as `f a -> f a`

Comment: @user12457 If it helps, think of it this way: We know `c` must be the same as `a`. We also separately know `c` must be the same as `f b`. The only way both can be true is if `a` is the same as `f b`.

Comment: Can anyone write code to demonstrate how it works. Thanks.

Comment: Choose to demonstrate how it works is ... a type checker. You can learn about writing those in the book *Types and Programming Languages*, by Benjamin Pierce. Or search online for lecture notes about programming language design by Shriram Krishnamurthi.

Comment: *Code* to demonstrate, I meant.